# Return a number from a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

I've been my banging head against the wall with the above question. Let's say I have the following class:

```
function Counter() {...}
```

so when I call the constructor:

```
var c= new Counter();
console.log(c); //return 0
```

furthermore If I created the following method:

```
Counter.prototype.increment = function() {
 return this += 1;
 };
```

it should increment c by 1 for every call

```
 c.increment(); // return c=1
 c.increment(); // return c=2
```

so far I have come  up with:

```
function Counter(){return Number(0)}
```

but still returns Number{}  not a zero...

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does `console.log(c);` return 0?

Comment: It looks like you want an object that sometimes acts like a plain number and sometimes acts like a number wrapped in an object. What is it that you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @Amberlamps It should return zero - that's what I am trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a value from the constructor because you instantiate it using the `new` keyword, this gives you a new instance of the object.

Store a property and increment that instead:

```
function Counter() {
    this.count = 0;
}

Counter.prototype.increment = function() {
    this.count++;
    return this.count;
};

var c= new Counter();

console.log( c.increment() ); // 1
console.log( c.increment() ); // 2
console.log( c.increment() ); // 3
```

Comment: it does achieve what I need - but how can I access 0? through c.count? ain't possible to get zero by just console.log(c) before any increment?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't allow for a custom `Object` type to directly imitate a primitive value. It also doesn't allow `this` to be assigned a new value.

You'll have to instead store the value within a property:

```
function Counter() {
    this.value = 0;
}

var c = new Counter();
console.log(c);        // Counter { value: 0 }
```

And, increment the value from it:

```
Counter.prototype.increment = function () {
    this.value += 1;
};

c.increment();
console.log(c.value);  // 1
```

Though, you can at least specify how the object should be converted to a primitive with a [custom `valueOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
Counter.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return this.value;
};

console.log(c.value);  // 1
console.log(c + 2);    // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
Counter.prototype.increment = function() {
 return this += 1;
 };
```

`this` is an object, += is not defined for objects.